# Как считать время в input с datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, jquery-validation, bootstrap-datepicker

Имеется input с подключенным bootstrap datetimepicker. Также задается defaultDate в котором дата задается с помощью moment.js. У меня такой код:

index.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Дата</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class='input-group' id="date">
            <input type='text' class="form-control" data-behavior="datetimepicker" placeholder="Дата" value="" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#date').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: moment().startOf('day').add(1, 'day'),
        });
    });
});
```

Теперь мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при отправке формы шла валидация этого input, и jquery validate проверял, что эта дата не ранее текущего момента.
Почитал документацию, нужно использовать isBefore, но я даже считать не могу эту дату. То есть console.log($('#date').val()) выдает пустое значение.

Перегуглил все, что можно, миллион способов вывести дату из datetimepicker, но вообще никак не выходит.

Пытаюсь так:

```
date =  $('#date');
console.log(moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm")); //Выведет правильный день, число и год, но время обнуляется. (21/06/2018, 00:00)
console.log(moment()); //выводит корректно (Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Thu Jun 21 2018 14:45:41 GMT+0700 (Индокитай), …})
console.log(moment(date)); //выводит в консоль объект и где-то в недрах есть та самая нужная дата, но не понимаю, как ее оттуда забрать. Полный путь- ._i["0"].jQuery3310055591916891772452.date
```

Comment: Вы задали инпуту идентификатор: `id="date"` но при этом в *main.js* обращаетесь не по айдишнику с помощью `jQuery`, а по имени класса: `$('.date').datetimepicker({...})`. Вам необходимо заменить `$('.date')` на `$('#date')` - тогда элемент будет найдет и дата будет положена в значение `value`.

Comment: Пробовал, как вы сказали, но нет. Если так сделать, то работать вообще ничего не будет. В моем случае все работает, не получается только вывести это значение, например в консоль.

Comment: Тут нет разницы, по айдишнику или по классу. Этого кода хватает, только что проверил, дата выводится, все супер. Не могу только подхватить эту дату и вывести в консоль. 
У себя поменял под айдишиники, разницы никакой. Просто обращение идет здесь: <div class='input-group date'>

Comment: А, ну если разницы в селекторе по имени класса и по идентификатору нет, то я не знаю. (Шучу, разница есть, но почему-то вы утверждаете обратное, для справки: [Basic selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/)). *Просто обращение идет здесь: <div class='input-group date'>* - скажу честно, я не понял. Подождем какого-нибудь гуру, возможно дадут ответ.

Comment: Да я имел в виду конкретно в этом случае не важно id это или класс. id="date" у инпута можно спокойно удалить, ничего не сломается.

Comment: Обновил сам пост.

Comment: Вы как-то странно задаете формат: `format("DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm")` для начала, сделайте так: `format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")` чтобы не было проблемы со временем делайте так: `moment.utc(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")`

Comment: Ввел таким образом: date =  $('.date'); console.log(moment.utc(startdate).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")); Ничем не отличается от 1 варианта. Обнуляет время, дата сегодняшняя.

Comment: Вам же объясняют, вы в `html` пишете `#date` и в селекторе `jquery` обращаетесь к классу `.date` - это 2 разные вещи. через `#`-это ид, через `.`-это класс.

Comment: Эм, не знаю, что у вас в `startdate` - если времени там нет и оно нулевое - то оно выведется нулевым. Далее, меня смущают слеши в формате: [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) , также разберитесь с селекторами, я прям уверен, что вы делаете что-то не так именно по этой причине.

Comment: И не понятно зачем использовать 2 раза готовность документа.  `$(document).ready(function() {});` - считай одно и тоже, что и это: `$(function() {});`

Comment: Со startdate дейстивительно ошибся. Поменял весь код, как вы хотели. Сейчас все работает, инпуту вообще не задавал ни id, ни класс. Но вывести в консоль значение инпута я так и не могу, val остается пустым.

Comment: Так вы его не задаете, с чего ему взяться-то в value? *2 раза готовность документа* - значит документ супер-готов :)

Comment: Вот я и говорю, если бы задавалось уже бы вывел так: console.log($('#date').val()); Поэтому ищу другой способ, так и не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывести дату из bootstrap datetimepicker получилось таким образом:

```
date = $('#date').data("DateTimePicker").date();
console.log(moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY, HH:mm"));
```